# python: how to replace a string in a list of string with a list of strings?

Tags: python, list

okay here is the example:

```
data = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'of', 'the', 'list']
replaceText = 'test'
replaceData =['new', 'test']
```

i did data.replace(replaceText, replaceData) but it doesn't work. How to replace a string in a list of string with a list of strings? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
The exact condition is to replace or split the words that contain "s" so I put a loop in it. So the end result will print 
    data = ['Thi', 'i', 'a', 'te','t', 'of', 'the', 'li','t']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a list, find the position of text with `.index()`, then replace by using slice assignment:

```
pos = data.index(replaceText)
data[pos:pos+1] = replaceData
```

This will replace only *one* occurrence of `replaceText` at a time. Demo:

```
>>> data = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'of', 'the', 'list']
>>> replaceText = 'test'
>>> replaceData =['new', 'test']
>>> pos = data.index(replaceText)
>>> data[pos:pos+1] = replaceData
```

To replace *all* occurences, use `pos` plus the length of `replaceData` to skip searching past the previous match:

```
pos = 0
while True:
    try:
        pos = data.index(replaceText, pos)
    except ValueError:
        break
    data[pos:pos+1] = replaceData
    pos += len(replaceData)
```

If you need to loop over `data` while modifying it, use a copy instead:

```
for n in data[:]:
    # maniplate data
```

Comment: actually the condition has made me to loop data. i posted the code above. would your method still work?

Comment: Your loop makes no sense. You cannot loop over `data` and change it in-place, for example. Do you mean that you'll replace multiple things at a time?

Comment: yah, the actually condition needs me to replace or split any string that contains the character 's', say 'test' will be replaced by 'te' and 't' to the list.

Comment: also "list" will be split in to "li" and "t" and replaced to the list.

Comment: @tipsywacky I've added an answer that does that (if I'm understanding correctly) - you may wish to update the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use list's [`index()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to find the position `p` of `replaceText`:

```
p = data.index(replaceText)
```

and then use the construct

```
data[start:end] = another_list
```

to replace elements from p to p+1 (end is not inclusive) with `replaceData`:

```
data[p:p+1] = replaceData
```

Note that `index()` throws `ValueError` if `replaceText` does not exist in `data`:

```
try:
  p = data.index(replaceText)
  data[p:p+1] = replaceData
except ValueError:
  # replaceText is not present in data, handle appropriately.
```

Answer (score 1):

> yah, the actually condition needs me to replace or split any string
>   that contains the character 's', say 'test' will be replaced by 'te'
>   and 't' to the list

```
from itertools import chain
data = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'of', 'the', 'list']
>>> filter(None, chain.from_iterable(el.split('s') for el in data))
['Thi', 'i', 'a', 'te', 't', 'of', 'the', 'li', 't']
```